# PreparedStatement with RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS cannot return generated key?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Some enviroment information:

1. mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;
2. mysql standard edition 5.5;
3. jdk 1.6;
4. Netbeans IDE;
5. Windows XP;

My Java codes is as below:

```
MySQLConnection conn = (MySQLConnection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "root", "");
String sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col1`,`col2`,...`colN`) VALUES (value1,value2,...,valueN)";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

The table has one primary key columen named "id" with auto_increment attribute. After the execution there is an inserted record in the table. However the the rs.next() return false and I cannot get the auto generated primary key value.

Any clue please?

Comment: Do you know that the MySQL JDBC driver implementation you're using supports this functionality?  And do you know that the record was INSERTed successfully and the primary key column populated in the database?

Comment: I am not sure about the first question actually. The JDBC driver is the newest version. For the second one, the record was inserted successfully and the primary key has been generated too. While I suppose that JDBC driver supports the function... If mysql does not support, is there any other way to get the auto generated primary key value?

Comment: Can you try if `stmt.executeUpdate(sql, new String]{"id"})` works? For some databases the columns to be returned have to be specified explicitly.

Comment: Looking at the MySQL Connector/J documentation it should work: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html